# Slow php socket server (~20 second delay)

Tags: php, sockets

Everything looks good on the iOS side. The data is written to `NSOutputStream` quickly. However, the `error_log` below is updated after about 20 seconds and then I get the response in my app.

Here is the php:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php –q
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

$server = stream_socket_server("tcp://---ip----:10001", $errno, $errorMessage);

while(true)
{
    $client = @stream_socket_accept($server);

    if ($client)
    {
        $client_data = stream_get_contents($client);
        if($client_data)
        {
            $json = json_decode($client_data, true);
            error_log("client data received: " . $client_data);

            //response code....
            fwrite($client, $output);

        }
        fclose($client);
    }
}
```

The lag is my main concern, but I'm also wondering if this code would work fine with multiple clients. It seems to work fine aside from the lag with one client. If this isn't good for multiple clients could someone point me in the right direction. Thanks.

**Apparent Solution**

I added the following code:

```
$client_data = stream_get_contents($client, 1);
$meta = stream_get_meta_data($client);
$unread_bytes = $meta['unread_bytes'];
$client_data .= stream_get_contents($client, $unread_bytes, 1);
```

Everything is fast now. If anyone objects to this solution, please do. PHP docs say don't use the `unread_bytes` but it seems to be a bit of a controversy and in this case it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would not work fine with multiple clients.You should use stream_select or epoll(libevent etc..) to handle multi clients.

You can try some asynchronous framework in php. For example [workerman](https://github.com/walkor/workerman) or [phpdaemon](https://github.com/kakserpom/phpdaemon).

Here is workermans demo.
Create test.php .

```
<?php
require_once './Workerman/Autoloader.php';
use Workerman\Worker;

// A worker listen 10001
$worker = new Worker("Text://0.0.0.0:10001");
// Create 4 processes
$worker->count = 4;
// When a client connect.
$worker->onConnect = function($connection){};
// When a client send a message.
$worker->onMessage = function($connection, $data)
{
    echo "Recv data:".$data."\n";
    $connection->send('Recv success!');
};
// When a client close connection.
$worker->onClose = function($connection){};
// Run all worker.
Worker::runAll();
```

Run width command `php test.php start` for debug mode or `php test.php start -d` for daemon mode.

Then you can use telnet command to test .

```
telnet ---ip---- 10001
Trying ---ip----...
Connected to ---ip----.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I hope that will help you.